# Does Solr support multiple types of nested docs per parent?

Tags: solr, nested

Using Solr 5.2.1

Can a parent have multiple types of nested docs or is it one type of child doc per parent document?

So for example

```
gathering: {
    location: { name: "The park", city: "New York", country: "United States Of America", ...}
    people: [
        { first_name: "John", last_name: "Smith", age: 21, ... }, 
        { first_name: "Jane", last_name: "Doe", age: 19, ...}
    ]
}
```

Is it possible with Solr 5.2.x or newer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can, there is no limitation on that different types of children docs. This can be achieved via [block-indexing](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Uploading+Data+with+Index+Handlers#UploadingDatawithIndexHandlers-NestedChildDocuments) and [BJQ](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Other+Parsers#OtherParsers-BlockJoinQueryParsers). In order to retrieve the child-documents one could use [child-transformation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Transforming+Result+Documents#TransformingResultDocuments-[child]-ChildDocTransformerFactory).

In order to debrief the index representation let me remind you the concept of index-block. Solr / Lucene don't provide native nested structures - they are storing documents sequentially in flat fashion (one after another):

[image: Simple Index Block representation]

`D0 / D5` stands for simple document from the collection, `D1, D2, D3, D4` are comprising own index-block. Lucene / Solr are providing means to index several documents as a single block: [IndexWriter#addDocuments()](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_2_1/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexWriter.html#addDocuments(java.lang.Iterable)).

What Solr / Lucene could actually do with such blocks - they mimic the nested structures relations. To make this relations happen one should introduce special field to distinguish documents. Let's say `type` - which type the document is: whether it is `gathering` (parent), `location` (child, type 1) or `people` (child, type 2):

[image: Block Join visual representation]

So after hooking it up at index-time you'll need to issue smth like:

1. `q={!parent which="type:gathering"}first_name:J*` (let's say you want to match by person's `first_name`). Note, you'll get parent documents only in the result-set.
2. In order to retrieve children docs you could supply [child-transformer](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Transforming+Result+Documents#TransformingResultDocuments-[child]-ChildDocTransformerFactory) as I mentioned: `fl=id,[child parentFilter=type:gathering limit=100]`.
3. The only limitation I can see here - you won't be able to model `location` as single-entity and group `people` into JSON array. This might be possible if you'll develop your custom response writer, but I think that's too complex and might be not case for your business scenario.

Comment: Do you know if it's possible using SolrJ library? When I have more than 1 child (annotation @Field(child=true)) in my Solr model I'm getting 'cannot have more than one Field with child=true'